# Accessing the pk from GET request returns a tuple

Tags: python, django, get

I have a 'Search' form consisting of 3 fields that provide some criteria for the eventual database query. The form submits via the GET method.

One of the fields is a ModelChoiceField and renders as a Select widget. The value of each option is the related object's primary key- In my case the default primary key assigned by Django. My understanding was that this value is an integer and is turned into a string in the request.

Therfore, in my view to handle the data I have `int(self.request.GET.get("name"))`.
However the error I get suggests the value is a tuple:

**TypeError Field 'id' expected a number but got (11,).**

**The above exception (int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple') was the direct cause of the following exception:**

Is there something I'm doing wrong? or otherwise how can I best retrieve this value as a integer so that I can complete my database filter:
`Product.objects.filter(id=product_id)`?

**UPDATE:**
I have added a method to the view which works but still wonder if there is a better way?:

```
def convert_to_int(self, type_tuple):
    """ Converts tuple value to integer """

    type_int = int(''.join(type_tuple))
    return type_int
```

Comment: Tyhen you can do something like `int(self.request.GET.get("name")[0])`

Comment: Instead, i have put a method in to convert it as the pk could be one or more digits

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and it turned out I had and extra comma after my function turning the statement into a tuple (very pythonic )

`request.form.get("name"),`

should be:

`request.form.get("name")`

this answer might be useful or help others with silly error.